# Same SOAP request to 3 different servers in PHP - parallel possible?

Tags: php, soap

Is it possible to run SOAP calls to 3 different servers simultaneuosly?

Example :

I have a PHP code that makes a SOAP call for, lets say: price and quantity of a product at three different APIs.
First, it makes a call at first supplier, that second and finnally third.

Is it possible to speed up this process? To make all calls at once, so the second call doesn't wait for first to finish?

Please give me some suggestions on how to handle it.

Comment: You can try with Guzzle http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#concurrent-requests

Comment: Check out this as well https://www.mullie.eu/parallel-processing-multi-tasking-php/